# how to resolve custom tag

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, tags

Here's my code:

```
str +=     "<td><fmt:formatDate value=\""+notices[i].noticeDuration+"\" type=\"date\" dateStyle=\"default\" pattern=\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm\" /></td>";
```

When I try to concatenate this string ,and output it on `body` tag,an error occurs, It says I lost a quotation.

When I remove this custom tag`<fmt:fromatDate>`, it works well.

How does it happen? Maybe the explore will resolve this custom tag in a different way?

Comment: rather than escaping `\"` you're probably better off using single quotations inside the string so it's easier to read `'`

Comment: coding by my colleague.I just help him to find the reason rather than solve this problem.haw-haw. anyway, really thanks.

Comment: I try, but still fail. Maybe this is not the key reason.

Comment: Can't seem to find any error when I try `innerHTML` it. Maybe it's `notices` that causing an issue. Try to replace that with a standard string.

Answer (score 0):

have you try this one ?

```
str += "<td><fmt:formatDate value='"+notices[i].noticeDuration+"' type='date' dateStyle='default' pattern='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' /></td>";
```